# RequireJS IE11 cache busting

Tags: spring-mvc, internet-explorer, caching, jboss, requirejs

We have a spring boot app and we requirejs to modularize the javascript part of the app. I currently use cache busting as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var require = {

        urlArgs: "bust=" + "${buildVersion}"
    };
</script>

<script data-main="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/main"
        src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/require.js"></script>
```

and then call the require js script which calls the main.js file.

This works fine on chrome, however on IE it works intermittenly. For some users it busts the cache and for some it doesnt.

The value ${buildVersion} is dynamic and is related to the build version as the name suggests

Comment: Hi, you could debug your app by using the dev tools' networking tab to inspect the request query string and response codes. F12>Networking tab, unselect "Always refresh from cache" then click the "Start" button. Pin the dev tool and then refresh the page,,, you would expect that the browser will force a refresh from the server only when the ${buildVersion} changes

Comment: Turns out we the buildVersion was a constant and not being changed.